# Cannot get Postgresql to start on Ubuntu Hardy

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04, postgresql

I am getting this error with Postgresql 8.4 on Ubuntu Hardy:

```
$./postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Cannot assign requested address
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

Here is my hosts file content (been finding a lot of stuff about this so just posting it now:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 Home-Dev
```

Update:
$ sudo netstat -tap | grep 5432
Came up blank.

I should also mention this is installed from source (I had original tried to install from the package and was getting the same error).

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgres start
```

If you installed postgres via the package manager try that.

If it fails again, please post the contents of: **sudo netstat -tap | grep 5432**

Comment: It's actually `/etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I had no loopback interface installed. When I installed it postgres started working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **127.0.1.1** is the IPv4 address of this machine that you are working on, I would like to point you to the following configuration files to look at:
(*the **directory/pathnames** may vary with relevance to your installation*). You may find them in /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/ (found here in Ubuntu 10.04)

- pg_hba.conf (/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf)

  - *Comment out the other parameters and drop in the following*

    - local   all         all                               trust
    - host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
    - host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
    - host all all 127.0.1.1 255.255.255.255 trust
- postgresql.conf (/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf)

  - *Ensure that the following parameter is pegged with a wildcard value*

    - listen_address = '*'
  - *Ensure that the following parameter is uncommented*

    - port = 5432

You may want to amend/modify the values in the future once you have your PostgreSQL service up and running. :-) Hope this will be helpful.